# How to resolve Okta redirection on github pages for vuejs app?

Tags: vue.js, authentication, okta

I have deployed a vuejs app on github-pages with okta authentication.  On localhost (locally) when I click on a login button on my vuejs page it goes to Okta for authentication and then redirects to my localhost successfully.

Now I have deployed to github-pages and the redirection from Okta back to my github-pages does not work.  I keep seeing the following error:
`GET https://<MYUSERNAME>.github.io/vue-catalog-ui/implicit/callback?code=<REDACTED>&state=<REDACTED> 404`

I guess Okta redirection does not work on Github-pages because locally I do this to run `npm run serve` which may do something additional like setting up a server?

The following is my Auth setup in my main.js file:

```
//const vueUrl = "http://localhost:8080"
const vueUrl = 'https://<MYUSERNAME>.github.io/vue-catalog-ui'

Vue.use(VueRouter)
console.log('issuer: ', process.env)
Vue.use(Auth, {
  issuer: 'https://dev-<REDACTED>.okta.com/oauth2/default',
  clientId: '<REDACTED>',  
  redirectUri: vueUrl + '/implicit/callback', // Handle the response from Okta and store the returned tokens.
  scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email'],
  pkce: true 
})
```

vue.config.js:

```
publicPath: '/vue-catalog-ui/'
```

Any hints appreciated.

Comment: Maybe give a try to Netlify/Vercel to see if it's working better.

Comment: Since it's a SPA, you have to configure your webserver to redirect all requests to your `index.html` page. I'm not sure you can do that on GitHub pages. Here's a guide for Heroku: https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/deploy-your-app/javascript/main/#heroku

Comment: Thanks @MattRaible.  Sounds about right to me too that I need a server to redirect requests to my index.html which seems to be happening with the magic of `npm run serve` locally.

Comment: Nothing magic here, just a webpack dev server running (SSR). Still, no way to have a regular simple callback from a valid auth? @MattRaible

Comment: If you have a callback URL that doesn't 404, everything should work just fine.